# Redraw listView in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to change css to selected item from image carousel plugin but my changes are not reflecting , for that i want to refresh listView component in react native.

```
<ListView
          initialListSize={10}
          onLayout={this.handlePreviewLayout}
          dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderImagePreview}
          onScroll={this.handleScrollRev}
          horizontal={true}
          scrollEnabled={true}
          ref={(comp) => { this._refPreviewListView = comp; return; }}
        />    
<View>
        <Image
          style={[
            styles.previewImage,
            previewImageStyle,
            { width: previewImageSize, height: previewImageSize },
            { borderRadius: this.state.borderRad }
          ]}
          source={getImageSourceFromDataSource(row)}
          resizeMode="cover">
        </Image>
        <View style={[styles.onlineStatus, { backgroundColor: this.badgeStatus }]} >
        </View>
      </View>
```

Comment: Firstly, we need to see some code to help you. Secondly, to refresh a listView you need to detroy/recreate its content. Share your code so we will be able to help you with examples.

Comment: hey @Facundo La Rocca thanks for replying me so soon ,in my question I have added my code please have look.